# (EXCEL)VBA Spin button which steps through in an sql databases date time

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have an sql Database table in MySQL which have lots of rows with varied date time values. For example:

```
2012-08-21 10:10:00   <-- with these date there are around 12 rows
2012-08-21 15:31:00   <-- with these date there are around 5  rows
2012-08-22 11:40:00   <-- with these date there are around 10 rows
2012-08-22 12:17:00   <-- with these date there are around 9  rows
2012-08-22 12:18:00   <-- with these date there are around 7  rows
2012-08-25 07:21:00   <-- with these date there are around 6  rows
```

If the user clicks on the SpinButton1_SpinUp() or SpinButton1_SpinDown() button then it should do the following:

The **SpinButton1_SpinUp()** button should filter out those data from an sql table which is the next after what we are currently on now.
Example: We have currently selected: 2012-08-21 15:31:00. The user hits the SpinUp button then the program selects those date from the database, which is the next higher value like this one: 2012-08-22 11:40:00. 
**So the user hits the SpinUp button the data which is selected in the database will change from those with date: 2012-08-21 15:31:00  to those with date: 2012-08-22 11:40:00**

The **SpinButton1_SpinDown()** will do exactly the reverse of the SpinUp button.
**When the user hits the SpinDown button the data which is selected in the database will change from those with date: 2012-08-21 15:31:00 to those with date 2012-08-21 10:10:00**

So I think the date which we are currently on, should be stored in a variable.
But on button hit not every bigger or lower data should be selected in the database, only those which are the closest bigger or the closest lower date.

**How can I do this?**

I hope I described my problem understandable. My native language is not english, so misunderstandings can occur! Please ask if you don't understand something! Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in your MySQL database displaying DISTINCT data values and use this as a data source of your spin button

```
CREATE VIEW DISTDATES as
SELECT DISTINCT mydate FROM mytable
```

You then can further join this date into mytable (e.g. a list field)